# How to change an array of java long type variable to java BigInteger class to support very large output?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming, biginteger

I am trying to update a Java program to support for very large output. Currently the program supports long type data, I'm trying to change the long type into BigInteger class.

Here is the original program,

```
class WaysDP_long
{
    static int A = 3;  
    static int B = 2;
    static int C = 2;
    
    static long CountWays(int a, int b, int c, long [][][]dp)
    {
        if (a > A || c >= C) return 0L; 
        if (b >= B) return 1L;    
        if (dp[a][b][c] != -1) return dp[a][b][c];
      
        long ways = 0;
        
        ways += CountWays(a+1, b, c+1, dp);
        ways += CountWays(a+1, b+1, c, dp);
        ways += CountWays(a+1, b+2, c, dp);
        ways += CountWays(a+1, b+4, c, dp);
      
        // Memorize and return
        return dp[a][b][c] = ways;
    }
  
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long[][][] dp = new long[A+1][B+5][C];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < A+1; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < B+5; j++)
                for(int k = 0; k < C; k++) dp[i][j][k]=-1L;
      
        System.out.println(CountWays(0, 0, 0, dp));
    }
}
```

To support larger values for A, B & C I was trying to convert some variables to BigInteger,
**Here is my updated code,**

```
class WaysDP_Large
{
    static int A = 3;  
    static int B = 2;
    static int C = 2;
    
    static boolean[][][] supportDP = new boolean[B+1][A+5][C];  //  to avoid BigInteger negative initialization.

    static BigInteger CountWays(int a, int b, int c, BigInteger [][][]dp)
    {
        if (a > B || c >= C) return BigInteger.ZERO;
        if (b >= A) return BigInteger.ONE;
        if (supportDP[a][b][c]) return dp[a][b][c];
        
        BigInteger ways = BigInteger.ZERO;
        
        ways.add(CountWays(a+1, b, c+1, dp));
        ways.add(CountWays(a+1, b+1, c, dp));
        ways.add(CountWays(a+1, b+2, c, dp));
        ways.add(CountWays(a+1, b+4, c, dp));
        
        // Memorize and return
        supportDP[a][b][c] = true;
        
        //dp[ballsPlayed][currentScore][wicketsGone] = new BigInteger();
        return dp[a][b][c] = ways;
    }
  
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigInteger[][][] dp = new BigInteger[B+1][A+5][C];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < B+1; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < A+5; j++)
                for(int k = 0; k < C; k++) supportDP[i][j][k] = false;
        
//      for(int i = 0; i < balls+1; i++)
//          for(int j = 0; j < target+5; j++)
//              for(int k = 0; k < wickets; k++) dp[i][j][k] = BigInteger.ZERO;
      
        System.out.println(CountWays(0, 0, 0, dp));
    }
}
```

But the updated code always gives an output 0, it should give **13**. [**for 3, 4, 3 it will be 20**]

Probably the problem with BigInteger assignment and adding. Any hints to overcome the problem will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You changed `ways += CountWays(a+1, b, c+1, dp);` to `ways.add(CountWays(a+1, b, c+1, dp));` They don't do the same thing, as `BigInteger` is immutable.

Comment: To achieve this "ways += CountWays(a+1, b, c+1, dp)" what changes I need, Please @tgdavies

Comment: `ways = ways.add(CountWays(a+1, b, c+1, dp))`